# Neural Network without external dependencies

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

is it possible to create a neural network without any external dependencies?
While searching around, everyone was using Numpy. Isn't it possible to write the neural network in plain Python?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Comment: Eventually the neural network is translated to 0's and 1's, like anything else, so you can also create it in a machine language if you want, but there is no reason to do that. `numpy` is just for doing the base level calculations at optimized efficiency. It's not like `keras` or `sklearn` that have an algorithem you may want to implement in another way.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a neural network in any language that you wish to use. A basic artificial neural network takes no more than plain multiplication and summation.

Comment: Do you have more Information about it? Something to read through or an example? Btw Thanks for your answer

Comment: I would suggest first you read into what a neural network really does, e.g. [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-neural-networks-19020b758230). For the implementation I suggest you use [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-your-own-neural-network-from-scratch-in-python-68998a08e4f6). The feed forward path is not much more than matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thanks. While searching I found this exact tutorial. They always used a numpy array as Input. Using a list should also work, right?

Comment: Yes, you can implement your own class to represent a matrix by any means you wish. A list or a basic array, whatever suits you best.